# Rewriting DevExtreme Dialog / Popup component to MaterialUI equivalent (react / javascript)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, dialog, popup

I'm moving away from using DevExtreme/DevExpress components, and the last one to go is my Popup / Dialog component.

The way the old popup worked, is that it was rendered in the background. The popup is rendered, but hidden, until a `visible` attribute is passed to it. I had it coded as the following:

```
            <UniversalPopupComponent
                popupDefinition={ownerDatabaseView}
                popupValues={databaseRowData}
                onSubmit={this.myPopupSubmitted}
                onCancel={this.myPopupCancelled}
                visible={this.state.popupVisibility}
            />
```

Material UI component does not seem to work the same way. For starters, how do I tell MaterialUI Dialog to only show when I click a button where the Dialog component is called, before I get to the part of actually adding data and processing data that is passed inside to generate the content?

I currently have the MUI progress (PopupMUI.js) :

```
class UniversalPopupComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            open: this.props.open
        }
    }

    handleClickClose = () => {
        this.setState({open: false})
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <Dialog open={this.state.open} onClose={this.handleClickClose}>
                <DialogContent>
                    placeholder
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                    <Button onClick={this.handleClickClose}> Close </Button>
                    <Button onClick={this.handleClickClose}> Submit </Button>
                </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>

        )
    }

}

export default UniversalPopupComponent;
```

and in App.js contains the following related things:

```
class App extends React.Component {
state = {
    open: false,
};

handlePopupOpen = () => {
    this.setState({open:true})

}

render() {
      return (
         <div> ...
                <Button onClick={this.handlePopupOpen}> Open Menu </Button>
                <UniversalPopupComponent open={this.state.open} />
         ... </div>
)}
```

I cannot get the Dialog to open this way, by passing the state of 'open' as 'true' to the Dialog inside the component with props.

However, if I have the below, then Dialog opens fine and closes fine too (click close is defined as just setState({open:false})

```
                <Button onClick={this.handlePopupOpen}> Open Menu </Button>
                <Dialog open={this.state.open} onClose={this.handleClickClose}>
                    <DialogContent>
                        placeholder
                    </DialogContent>
                    <DialogActions>
                        <Button onClick={this.handleClickClose}> Close </Button>
                        <Button onClick={this.handleClickClose}> Submit </Button>
                    </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
```

I have not set up to pass any data yet, as the big problem is that the dialog won't open for me to start setting everything up and re-writing parts.

Answer (score 0):

So my stupid brain completely forgot that, once something is in constructor, it does not get updated. So I was passing the `open` prop, but only writing it once.

I simply added a `componentDidUpdate` that compares current state of Open to new state of Open from prop, if they are different, write new state of prop.

Then I added a callback, so that when something is closed, it sets the state of open to false, which updates the component and closes the menu.